# How to set Image on CircleImageView when i clicked it?

Tags: android

Here i want to create one circleimageview and set image on it from gallarIn which i create one circleimageview 
how to set images from gallary in circleimage view?

**My Xml file**

```
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/profile_image"
         android:layout_width="76dp"
         android:layout_height="76dp"
         android:src="@drawable/profile"
     </de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>
```

Here i created object of circeimageview
and pass intent for choose image from gallary

**In Java File**

```
     profileImage =(de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Profile Pic",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
        }
    });

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap bm=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm =    MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    profileImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Help me to solve this.

want to create profile picture with circle image view.?

i found so many tutorial but there have no onclick event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            profileImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to transform an image into circular shape the try Picasso library it is easy to use and you can use circle transformation to set into image view .Google it you will find lots of examples

Comment: Thank you but don't want to use picasso.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i found the answer finally

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp">

</de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>
```

Here,

**android:Clickable="true"**

Solve  my problem

Thanks to all

Comment: Thanks all for replay